# How to ensure the use tag using in C#

Tags: c#, .net, using

Is there any way to ensure that a class will always be used as a using instead of being instantiated normally

Desired way
`using(var db = new DbContext()) {}`

Common way `var db = new DbContext();`

I'd like somehow to prevent instantiating the common form.
I already know that to use the 'using' it is necessary to implement IDisposable

Comment: Short anser: no.

Comment: Sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Care to elaborate why you would want to do this?

Comment: Long answer: you can't, because the using uses the "common way" only, it calls db.Dispose() when you get out of the using block.

Comment: Thank you. It has some junior developers on staff, and I would like to ensure that it will not be possible to start a context without invoking the dispose method.

Comment: Terrible title, by the way. "ensure the use tag using" doesn't make sense to me.  perhaps "How to ensure the user uses the "using" statement in C#"

Comment: Notice that FxCop (built-in into Visual Studio) will trigger a warning/error for non-disposed variables if you set it up: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot.

---

However, if that is an option, you *can* write methods that ensure that nobody has to even instantiate your object and make mistakes disposing it:

For example:

```
var instance = new YourObject();

var result = instance.MethodCallNeeeded(17);

// oops, no .Dispose called, basic mistake
```

How about another way of offering your functionality to your users:

```
public static TResult UseYourObject<T>(Func<YourObject, TResult> func)
{
    using(var x = new YourObject())
        return func(x);
}
```

Providing only this method means people *cannot* forget the `using` because they are not responsible for creation and disposing of the object.

Usage would be:

```
var result = ClassName.UseYourObject(instance => instance.MethodCallNeeeded(17));
```

---

And as the perhaps best option: do code reviews and static code analysis with your juniors. *Teach* them how to do this. That's why they are juniors.